# Copying argv to a new global vector string

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to copy argv to a new vector of strings which I want it to be global so I can use it in another function:

here i'm using this line to copy argv : `std::vector<std::string> args( argv, argv + argc );`

```
std::vector< std::string> args; //global

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    if(argc <2 ||argc-2 != atoi(argv[1])){
        cout << "illegal arguments" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    std::vector<std::string> args( argv, argv + argc ); // copying here
// some more code in the main (works fine)
```

}

And here i'm using it (another function in the same file):

```
void* ATM_Threads(void* atm_id){
    int* id=(int*) atm_id;
    stringstream buff;
    //buff <<"ATM_"<<*id<<"_input_file.txt"; // using this line instead of the next one works just fine
    buff<<args[*id+1]; //here i'm using the vector which gives me core dumped SF
    }
```

But im getting segmentation fault.. any idea why?

Comment: What does the debugger tell you?

Comment: Where is the global?

Comment: Can you please create a [mcve]. Also, you should really get a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to learn more about *modern* C++.

Comment: Try enabling the `-Wshadow` warning of your compiler

Comment: Updated. I will try -Wshadow now

Comment: I have no idea why you guys put it off-topic as I really didn't know that it defines only a localvariable that hides the global. I think that it can help others. 
Voting it off-topic just to make yourselves look good is not needed.

Comment: @Ameerkhan Neither did the voters know that it defines a local variable because you failed to give them a [mcve].

Comment: I read that thing thousand times. I really gave you the best I can.

Comment: I showed what example does work and which one doesn't work. 
If others didn't understand doesnt give them the privilege to vote it down and off-topic @user2079303

Comment: @Ameerkhan the example code that you gave [doesn't compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b3d1a11663ce9468). If your problem is a segmentation fault, then the code must be compilable to reproduce the problem. Please try to make your example reproduce the problem that you describe.

Comment: @user2079303 you are right! Didn't really know that by complete you meant compilable. I think it is compilable now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> std::vector<std::string> args( argv, argv + argc ); // copying here
> ```

This doesn't copy anything to a globally declared `args`. This defines a local automatic variable `args` that hides the  global `args`. The global `args` remains empty. Therefore `args[*id+1]` will be outside the bounds of the global `args`.

> any idea how to copy it to a global array or vector?

You can insert elements into a vector using the `insert` member function:

```
args.insert(args.end(), argv, argv + argc);
```

Or `std::copy`:

```
std::copy(argv, argv + argc, std::back_inserter(args));
```

Comment: Okay, any idea how to copy it to a global array or vector?

Comment: @Ameerkhan see the edit.

Comment: @Ameerkhan then please mark the answer as accepted